# Can't change array passed inside function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say we have an array `a = [1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to zero it `[0,0,0,0,0]` by using function.
This works:

```
function clear (arr) {
  arr.forEach((element, index) => {arr[index] = 0});
}
```

But this don't:

```
function clear2 (arr) {
  arr = [...arr].fill(0);
}
```

Just `arr.fill(0)` inside `clear2()` works, but it's running inside Vue.js so I can't assign array elements by index, I need to reassign array var completely to remain reactivity.

Why `clear2()` doesn't work? Arrays as a case of Objects should be passed by reference, so what am I doing wrong?

*Update:* I use it as a on-click method in Vue so I can't return from it and want to pass different arrays as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
  arr = [...arr].fill(0);
```

you're creating a copy of the original array then chaning that copy's values and then setting the parameter's reference value to the new array (you're not updating the parameter's inner state)

with

```
arr.forEach((element, index) => {arr[index] = 0});
```

you're actually updating the array parameter inner state

Comment: So by `arr = [...arr].fill(0)` it should assign newly created zeroed array to `arr` ref, but actually it changes `arr` only inside function, not outside, although `arr` should be a link to outer array.

Comment: The arr parameter inside the function is a copy of the outer arr REFERENCE. By doing arr = [...arr].fill(0); inside the function, you're reassigning the reference copy. 
Instead of doing arr = [...arr].fill(0); try just doing arr.fill(0, 0); inside the function

Comment: I can't do `arr.fill(0)` -- it breaks reactivity

Comment: Ok, but if you want your clear function to change the items within the arr parameter then you either have to use `arr.forEach((element, index) => {arr[index] = 0});` or `arr.fill(0,0)` within the function. If instead you want to return a new copy of the array filled with zeros, then doing `return [...arr].fill(0);` is the way to go

Comment: The question is -- why `arr` parameter inside the function is valid reference to global array for `forEach()` but not valid reference for assigning new array?

Comment: let's put it this way... let's change the name of your variable to foo and let's say you call clear(foo). the arr parameter inside of the clear function is a pointer (actually is a reference copy) to the foo array. you can use the arr parameter to change foo's inner state, but if you reassign the arr parameter then you would be changing the arr pointer (not the inner state)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Description) directly, because

> The `fill` method is a mutable method, it will change this object itself, and return it, not just return a copy of it.

```js
function clear(array) {
    array.fill(0);
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

clear(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I can't do it because I use this function as a method in Vue.js so I can't alter array by accessing by indices and `fill()` looks work like it. So I need to assign to a variable new array as a whole.